# Improving Regexp performance

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I have the following Regex code that's taking a long time (30+ seconds) to validate large URLS:

```
let validReg = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i');
let isValid = validReg.test(component.repository_url);
```

How can I change this code to validate the same Regex more efficiently?

Comment: Why is this tagged as Python? This looks like JavaScript.

Comment: If it was Python, you'd skip the regex and use a dedicated URL parsing API, e.g. [urllib.parse.urlparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse). Parsing complicated formats with a regex is typically a terrible idea (even if it works, it's rarely maintainable).

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark thanks for pointing out the mistake. this is Javascript.

Comment: Since it is JavaScript one would use parser based approaches as well ... the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) provides [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor the part where you match hyphen separated word chars: `[a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*` => `[a-z\\d]+(?:-+[a-z\\d]+)*`.

Also, note you do not need to escape `/` chars, they are not special regex metacharacters, and you are not using a regex literal.

You may use

```js
let validReg = new RegExp('^(https?://)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]+(?:-+[a-z\\d]+)*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(:\\d+)?(/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i');
let isValid = validReg.test(component.repository_url);
```

Comment: @Travis This alone won't crash anything. What was the input string?

Comment: Actually you're right, I am unable to get it to crash now, so I must have made an error on my end. My apologies!